# Rails 3 has_many :through form with dropdown menus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, formtastic

I'm trying to implement a has_many :through join in Rails 3 (with Formtastic) and I'm a little stuck. I have the models set up as follows:

**Models:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :employees, :through => :teams
has_many :teams

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :projects, :through => :teams
has_many :teams

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :employee
```

And this line gives me a multi-select box in the projects view that allows employees to be selected:

**View:**

```
<%= f.input :employees, :as => :select %>
```

So far this gets the job done, but what I'd LIKE to have is a separate dropdown box to select each employee's name, then their role in the project. I can't figure out the form code to get me there...

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I've gotten the code from [Railscast 197: Nested Model Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) working and it's part-way there. This is what I have in the view:

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :employees do |builder| %>
     <%= render 'employee_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "add employee", f, :employees %>
```

and the 'employee_fields' partial:

```
<p class="fields">
    <%= f.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => Employee.find(:all) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
```

But right now this creates a new employee rather than a new team (project-employee join record), so I think it's acting as a `has_many` rather than a `has_many :through`. How can I edit this so that the `:name` input above adds a record to `project[employee_ids][]`?

Comment: The railscasts.com episodes on nested model forms, numbers 196 & 197, may provide some ideas. They are not specifically on `has_many :through` but they do provide the ability to have multiple child fields for a parent object.

Comment: I just watched those last night! I got that functionality working, but I'm still stuck on the `has_many :through` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god, I finally got this thing to work. Here's the relevant code, minus the bits added to make the form add and remove fields dynamically:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= semantic_form_for @project do |f| %>
    .
    .
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :teams do |builder| %>
        <input id="project_teams_none" name="team[employee_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
        <%= render 'team_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
```

**_team_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="input">
    <%= f.collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
</div>
```

The key was adding the `<input id="project_teams_none" name="team[employee_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />` line in manually, because for whatever reason this wasn't generated as part of the form. This got the form to actually start updating things, and then I just had to make the nested form refer to the join model (`team`) rather than to `employees` so that the updates were going to the right place.

Looks so simple now!